# Using an L293D chip (to control a motor) with a separate power supply

Tags: gpio, power, electronics, pi-b+

I've got an L293D Motor Driver chip powered by 4.5v via some batteries and am trying to send high signals via the GPIO library in Python to control a motor, however this does not seem to work. My code is simply (pin 4 being GPIO 4 -- physical pin 7, my input pin):

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.OUT)
gpio.output(4, gpio.HIGH)
```

Now, this works for a single LED, but doesn't when I connect a wire (as the input) from pin 2, 7, 10 or 15 (the inputs).

The chip and motors *do* work, as if I manually take the inputs to high/low, they turn appropriately.

I presume it is not working because of the power supply voltage differences -- the motor circuit might not recognize the lower HIGH voltage from the Pi as being HIGH...?

What can I do to make this work?

---

L293D pinout:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always worth double checking the connections if a circuit doesn't work.

Remember that you also need to connect a Pi ground to an external device you want to control from a Pi GPIO.  WIthout the ground there will be no return path for the control signal.

Answer (score 2):

You need common ground as @joan says.  A pull-up resistor may be needed if the driver chip isn't grok king 3v3 as "high".   Test the motor driver with 3v input with a jumper lead.